# Cannot autheticate gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to authenticate my `gcloud`. I can run `gcloud init` and everything goes smoothly but the terminal does not proceed beyond giving me the link to open the authentication browser link.

I run:

```
gcloud init
```

and, I get

```
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.                                                      
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

You must log in to continue. Would you like to log in (Y/n)?  Y
```

I proceed with Y and it automatically opens the browser tab and asks me to log in to my google account. meanwhile the terminal has reached

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=nAOd8W8sIVuPPQyBtbdolPPSAUctM67&access_type=offline&code_challenge=pBvvLeTf4D1x7AuhvuOkCsv8Yxq6-ldWOKs5AP3YPn0&code_challenge_method=S256
```

I successfully log in to my google account and it gives me

```
You are now authenticated with the gcloud CLI!
```

But, the terminal remains stuck at the screen and nothing happens. I forcibly quit it with ctrl+c

I run

```
gclouds projects list
```

and I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.

If you have already logged in with a different account:

    $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

--no-browser or --no-console options do not help as well as nothing happens post pasting the key in my terminal. And I have to forcibly quit the browser and then I find out that gcloud has not been authenticated.

How to get my gcloud authenticated?

Comment: Do you have file access restriction on your computer? Directories not writable or not readable?

Comment: I am sure here are many directories are not readable and writable without root privileges. But, I do not think such exist within my user. Is there any place specific you want me to look into?

Comment: There is something wrong with your system. As a workaround create a service account and authorize the CLI with the service account.

Comment: @figs_and_nuts after 2 years, did u figure out the issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Burned down the forest. I reinstalled my operating system. In my attempts to solve other problems with gcloud and Google's ever-so customer-centric intuitive design choices, I had done irreparable (by me) damage to something on my system that wasn't allowing gcloud to be authenticated

Answer (score 1):

This may be a permission problem in the user profile; just see where it fails to write:

```
strace -e trace=open,close,read,write gcloud init
```

Comment: I can run this command but, I am afraid I do not know what to make of it. Can you tell me how I can better help you help me?

Comment: The command you have given also seems to be waiting for something. I get ```[2] Create a new configuration\n", 32 [2] Create a new configuration
) = 32
write(2, "Please enter your numeric choice"..., 35Please enter your numeric choice:  ) = 35
read(0, 
``` and the cursor is at the end and the command does not return

Comment: You could as well add a new user and start with a fresh profile. It cannot list, read or write in `~`.

Comment: Please stop spamming me with irrelevant logs, which have little to do with it. While `gcloud init` cannot create, read and write `~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default`, this will not work. And it doesn't get "stuck", but it awaits interactive (keyboard) input.

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/.config/gcloud/configurations && sudo chown -R user:group ~/.config` ...